# Reading information from file

Tags: c

In C I'm trying to read a line data from a file and save it.
I think i'm opening it properly but when I try to print it, it isn't working properly

example: I'm trying to read a line with:

```
20 3.1 U
```

I'm using fscanf but it is only reading the first data properly.
What I've been trying

```
fscanf(fr, "%d","%f","%s",&age, &grade, class);
```

Am I getting the parameter format wrong?
When I only do the first parameter it works fine

```
fscanf(fr, "%d",&age, &grade, class);
```

I'm trying to use printf to print

```
printf("%d","%f","%s",age, grade, class);
```

only age is printing properly

Comment: The format argument is a single string, e.g. `"%d%f%s"`

Comment: what are you doing playing editing editing.

Comment: Try ***reading the documentation***.  [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) and [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format specifiers for both `fscanf` and `printf` need to be a single string.

So for example, the following might work for you:

```
fscanf(fr, "%d%f%s", &age, &grade, class);
```

and

```
printf("%d, %f, %s", age, grade, class);
```

Comment: Note: the spaces in `"%d %f %s"` are not needed, but do no real harm.

Comment: Thanks I was wondering, using %f should be fine to read the decimal 3.1 correct?
my printf keeps outputting some huge number starting with -92559604

Comment: Use `%f` to read to `float`, use `%lf` to read into `double`.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it thanks
thanks Weather Vane I just realized that too